# Spectrum of general projection and orthogonal projection

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, projection, self-adjoint-operators

I am trying to think about this, but I seem to be stuck. Suppose $P$ is a projection on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. If I am just talking about a general projection, where I only know that $P^2=P$, can I deduce that the spectrum of $P$ can only consist of $0$ and $1$? What about if $P$ is also orthogonal, meaning $P^*=P$?
Can I also say something about the type of spectrum in terms of classification to point (eigenvalues), residual, and continuous?
I am relatively new to operators and functional analysis, so my toolbox might be a bit limited here. I thank all helpers for any and all help.

Comment: Projection is orthogonal iff self-adjoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the formula $\sigma(P)^2=\sigma(P^2)=\sigma(P)$ holds, the spectrum of $P$ is contained in $\{0,1\}$. The condition $P=P^*$ is not necessary for this.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. Is the formula you mention for the spectrum of a power of an operator true in general for linear operators on Hilbert spaces?

Comment: @kroner Yes, if $p$ is a polynomial and $T \in B(H)$, then $\sigma(p(T)) = p(\sigma(T))$. This even holds for continuous functions $p$ on the spectrum of $T$!

Comment: thank you very much, is there a reference where I can find a proof of this?

Comment: @kroner: what you are looking for is "Spectral Mapping Theorem" and, more generally, Functional Calculus.

Answer (score 2):

Being orthogonal makes no difference in terms of what the spectrum is. You have

- if $P=I$, then $\sigma(P)=\{1\}$;
- if $P=0$, then $\sigma(P)=\{0\}$;
- if $P$ is not $0$ nor $I$, then $\{0,1\}\subset\sigma(P)$ (because $P(I-P)=0$ shows that neither can be invertible) and for any $\lambda\in\mathbb C\setminus\{0,1\}$ one can check directly that
  $$
  (P-\lambda I)^{-1}=\frac1{\lambda(1-\lambda)}\,P-\frac1\lambda\,I.
  $$

In summary, if $P^2=P$ then

- $\sigma(P)=\{1\}$ if and only if $P=I$;
- $\sigma(P)=\{0\}$ if and only if $P=0$;
- $\sigma(P)=\{0,1\}$ if and only if $P\ne 0,I$.

In all cases the spectrum agrees with the point spectrum. For if $x\in P\mathcal{H}$, then $Px=x $ and so $1$ is an eigenvalue.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer